# Selenium: Automate Vertical Scrolling in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll

I need to automate scrolling down using the scroll bar. [This is what the scroll bar looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upAV7.jpg) 
This is the html code of the scroll bar:

```
<div class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-vertical">
    <div class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-drag" style="top: 132.253px;">
        <div class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-home" title="Home"></div>
        <div class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-up" title="Previous"></div>
        <div class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-down" title="Next"></div>
        <div class="z-biglistbox-wscroll-end" title="End"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think of maybe clicking the "Next" button of the scroll bar but my code's not working. I did something like the following:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", scroll_down);
```

.

```
WebElement scroll_down = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".z-biglistbox-wscroll-down"));
scroll_down.click();
```

Neither of the two worked. Can anyone give me an idea how to do it?

UPDATE:
This problem was already solved. Refer to **alecxe's** answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725033/selenium-click-not-always-working) for the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascriptexecutor directly for scrolling. Below code might give you some idea.

**Case 1:** To scroll upto a certain element so that the expected element will be visible

```
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

//Identify the WebElement which will appear after scrolling down
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mCSB_3_container']/p[3]"));

// now execute query which actually will scroll until that element is not appeared on page.
je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
```

**Case 2:** To scroll upto a certain element

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,400)");
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you but this didn't work for me. The problem is fixed tho, refer to the update on the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("z-biglistbox-wscroll-down"));
element.click();
```

You can use this but it will click only once in the scroll down element.

Comment: It's not working. It's not clicking the down arrow even once.

Comment: `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='z-biglistbox-wscroll-vertical']//div[@class='z-biglistbox-wscroll-down']"));
element.click();` try this know.Is there any iframe there in the dom?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for scrolling your window to bottom :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsx.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)", "");
```

Comment: Thank you but this didn't work for me. My problem is fixed tho, refer to the update on the question.