# Selenium How to click on div inside IFrame

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe, automation

I am building a application that should help smaller local business to get google reviews from there customers easier. For that I am using Selenium in Python.

This is the procedure explained:

1. In chrome i open the direct review link.
2. The review link first loads the google maps page and then the pop-up
   window opens with the star rating selection at the top and below the
   review input box.
3. I want with selenium to select the 5th star.

This is my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

review_link = "https://g.page/r/CQcv68N5l734EB0/review"

# Set up the Chrome webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

# Load the review page and wait for it to load
driver.get(review_link)
time.sleep(10)

# Switch to the iframe containing the review stars
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.NAME, "goog-reviews-write-widget"))
time.sleep(5)

# Click the 5th star using its CSS selector
five_star = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#kCvOeb > div.O51MUd > div.Ugvple > div > div.WGh5lc.u4Qsab > div > div:nth-child(5)")
five_star.click()

# Switch back to the main page
driver.switch_to.default_content()

print("selected five stars")

# Close the webdriver
driver.quit()
```

Just as a note, i know that `WebDriverWait()` is better than `time.sleep()`. The reason i choose `time.sleep()` is for simplicity and easier testing. In production i would change it to `WebDriverWait()`. Same story with the css selector, i will change this in future to a simpler XPath.

With the code above i am getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: 
Message: element click intercepted: Element <iframe name="goog-reviews-write-widget" role="presentation" class="goog-reviews-write-widget" src="https://www.google.com/maps/api/js/ReviewsService.LoadWriteWidget2?key=AIzaSyAQiTKe3tivKXammrJ6ov6u8E7KwZPNFss&amp;authuser=0&amp;hl
=en&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp;pb=!2m1!1sChIJselsQL2hmkcRBy_rw3mXvfg!7b1&amp;cb=26368821" 
cd_frame_id_="c0287439a9a949d63db71626600d7c1c"></iframe> is not clickable at point (780, 184). 

Other element would receive the click: <iframe name="goog-reviews-write-widget" role="presentation" class="goog-reviews-write-widget" src="https://www.google.com/maps/api/js/ReviewsService.LoadWriteWidget2?key=AIzaSyAQiTKe3tivKXammrJ6ov6u8E7KwZPNFss&amp;authuser=0&amp;hl=en&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp;pb=!2m1!1sChIJselsQL2hmkcRBy_rw3mXvfg!7b1&amp;cb=14671787"></iframe>
```

As I understand it, the Iframe intercepts the click. This is the selector of the 5th star, that i am using:
[image]

Why do i have to switch to Iframe anyways you ask maybe? This is because, if i don't switch to IFrame, the css selector to the 5th can't be found. Here is the IFrame i am referring to:
[image]

My attempts of solving this were:

1. Using the css selector of 5th star svg inside the div of the 5th star. Here I also got a `ElementClickInterceptedException`, but this the click was intercepted by the div in which the svg is inside and that i am clicking in the above code from me. Also the click didn't when trough as the 5th star wasn't selected.
2. using javascript click method:

   `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", five_star)`

With this line instead of the `.click()` method, the code went trough without any exceptions but the click didn't apply the 5th star.

**I am now getting out of ideas how to solve this problem. How could I click on the 5th Star inside the Iframe?**

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725033/selenium-click-not-always-working)

I am now using a action chain with move to element and the click works:

```
five_star = account.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#kCvOeb > div.O51MUd > div.Ugvple > div > div.WGh5lc.u4Qsab > div > div:nth-child(5)")

ActionChains(account.driver).move_to_element(five_star).click().perform()
```